# "The kernel failed to start due to an error with the 'pyzmq' module. Consider re-installing this module." error in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to import the module "gym_super_mario_bros" for a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eeYqJ0uBKE&t=503s). I'm using Jupyter in VSCode, but every time I press shift+enter to run the code:

```
import gym_super_mario_bros
```

I get the error
`The kernel failed to start due to an error with the 'pyzmq' module. Consider re-installing this module.`

I've tried reinstalling the pyzmq module about a few thousand times, but for some reason it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Following this link:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Failure-to-start-kernel-due-to-failures-related-to-pyzmq-module

You can perform the following to fix it:

```
 # if using a non-conda environment
python -m pip install ipykernel pyzmq -U --force-reinstall
# if using a conda environment
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel pyzmq --name <environment name> --update-deps --force-reinstall
```